# NPM - npm watch not working

Tags: npm

I'm creating a simple npm watch to watch and generate a sass file.

I have this code

```
    {
      "name": "npm-test",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
         "scss": "node-sass --output-style compressed -o css/output css/*scss",
         "watch": "watch 'npm run scss' css/*.scss"

      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "node-sass": "^3.7.0",
        "watch": "^0.18.0"
      }
    }
```

I'm getting this error

```
    > npm-test@1.0.0 watch /Users/ch-d/Desktop/npm-test
    > watch 'npm run scss' css/*.scss

    > Watching css/main.scss
    /Users/ch-d/Desktop/npm-test/node_modules/watch/main.js:73
        if (err) throw err;
                       ^
    Error: ENOTDIR, scandir 'css/main.scss'
        at Error (native)

    npm ERR! Darwin 15.4.0
    npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "watch"
    npm ERR! node v0.12.4
    npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! npm-test@1.0.0 watch: `watch 'npm run scss' css/*.scss`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the npm-test@1.0.0 watch script 'watch 'npm run scss' css/*.scss'.
    npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the npm-test package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    npm ERR!     watch 'npm run scss' css/*.scss
    npm ERR! You can get their info via:
    npm ERR!     npm owner ls npm-test
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     /Users/ch-d/Desktop/npm-test/npm-debug.log
```

I can run 'npm run scss' and that works but not the watch

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using [watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/watch), it only takes a directory argument at the command line, not a file wildcard. I just confirmed this on my own system...

You can use watch programmatically to do more interesting or complex things...but the CLI is pretty basic.

You can change the line to `watch 'npm run scss' css/` or you can look into something more programmatic such as a watch-script or something more complex, like a grunt- or gulp-based approach.

Answer (score 0):

Also be aware under **Windows OS**. Using Windows I encountered issues using simple quotes. Following was NOT working for me:

```
"watch:css": "watch 'npm run scss' ./scss --interval=1"
```

whereas the next one was correct:

```
"watch:css": "watch \"npm run scss\" ./scss --interval=1"
```

**Notice the escaped quotations**.